# div reloading wrong after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script for adding and removing entries from a table. it does this using ajax to call a php script. On success it's supposed to reload the div containing the table. At the moment it just empties the div.

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add_height_weight").click(function(){
        var corp_hw_name = $("#corp_hw_name").val();
        var corp_hw_height = $("#corp_hw_height").val();
        var corp_hw_weight = $("#corp_hw_weight").val();       
        var client_id = $("#cient_id").val();
        var ff_id = $("#ff_id").val();
        var task = "add";

        var dataString = "task=" + task + "&client_id=" + client_id + "&ff_id=" + ff_id + "&corp_hw_name=" + corp_hw_name + "&corp_hw_height=" + corp_hw_height + "&corp_hw_weight=" + corp_hw_weight;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/organiseit/fact_finds/processors/corp_health.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                alert("Height/Weight Updated");
                $("input,textarea,option").css("background-color","#fff");
                $("#height_weight_table").load(" #height_weight_table");
            }
        });  
    });

});
```

And here's the content of the div

```
<div id="height_weight_table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td>Height</td><td>Weight</td><td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    $ff_height_weight = fetch_all("SELECT * FROM ff_height_weight WHERE ff_id='$ff_id'");
    foreach($ff_height_weight as $entry){ 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry['height']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry['weight']; ?></td>
            <td><button class="delete_act" onclick="delete_height_weight('<?php echo $entry['id']; ?>')">X</button></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' id="corp_hw_name"></td>
            <td><input type='number' id="corp_hw_height"></td>
            <td><input type='number' id="corp_hw_weight"></td>
            <td><button class='new_note_submit' id="add_height_weight">+</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions why this would reload an empty div?

I have similar code running elsewhere in the project for adding/deleting from a notes table. The following code works perfectly but I can't see how it differs from the code above:

javascript

```
if(proceed === "TRUE"){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/organiseit/clients/update_client_notes.php",
            data: noteString,
            success: function(){
                alert("data submitted");
                $("#notes_table").load(" #notes_table");
                $("#new_note").css("background-color","#fff");
            }
        });
```

div on the page

```
<div class="notes_area" id="notes_area">
<table class="notes_table" id="notes_table">
    <tr>
        <td class="note_body"><strong>Note</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Created by</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Created for</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Date Created</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Completion by</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Delete</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if(!empty($id)){
        $get_note = fetch_all("SELECT * FROM client_notes WHERE client_id=$id ORDER BY id DESC");
        foreach($get_note as $note){?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $note["note"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $note["created_by"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $note["note_for"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $note["date"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $note["completion_by"];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><button class="delete_note" onclick="delete_note(<?php echo $id.",".$note["id"];?>)"><strong>X</strong></button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>  
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, (the working one) you are targeting the table which has an `id` of `"#notes_table"`. This is why the ajax request is successful in finding the table.

```
//What you are targeting in AJAX request
$("#notes_table").load(" #notes_table");

//the actual markup for the page is correct for the request
<div class="notes_area" id="notes_area">
   <table class="notes_table" id="notes_table">
```

In your first example you are targeting the parent div, not the table itself, your ajax request is trying to get the entire div not the table:

```
//What you are targeting in AJAX request
$("#height_weight_table").load(" #height_weight_table");

//here you are actually targeting the parent div not the table
<div id="height_weight_table">
    <table>
```

Try switching the `id` for the `<div>` to the `<table>` element.

```
<div>
    <table id="height_weight_table">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I gave this a try but got the same result. I moved the ID from the parent div into the table element as described. Result was it removed all the contents between the `<table></table>` tags

Comment: Are you sure the request actually completes? If you open developer tools on the browser and check network traffic you will see if the response returns 200 (success) or not. Maybe you arent targeting the php file correctly.

Comment: yes, request definitely completes. tools shows the 200 status, besides that the php script successfully does the adding and removing from the database part without error so the PHP script is working.

Comment: Try the following and let me know whats returned:         `$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/organiseit/fact_finds/processors/corp_health.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                alert( "Your returned element id = " + data[0].id  );
                $("input,textarea,option").css("background-color","#fff");
                $("#height_weight_table").load(" #height_weight_table");
            }
        }); `

Comment: "corp_health.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Comment: Okay, so your request doesn't actually return what you think it does. It should return an array if the ajax request is successful. Maybe its hitting the php file okay but not finding the html markup you are looking for. This time try `$("#height_weight_table").html(data);`

Comment: Okay, tried that. it emptied the contents between the `<table></table>` tags. I assume because the data array is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading the received data in the `div`. You have to declare and use that data in the `success` function. Try this...

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/organiseit/fact_finds/processors/corp_health.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Height/Weight Updated");
        $("div#height_weight_table").replaceWith(data);
        $("input,textarea,option").css("background-color","#fff");
    }
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I don't think this is what I'm trying to do. To clarify: when the ajax call is successful it should reload the divs current contents, not replace it with new contents. Because the div contains PHP to retrieve values from the database, and these may be have changed since the page was first loaded, the contents of the table should be different as a result. I've made this work elsewhere on the project, I'll edit my post to include an example that works and perhaps we can locate where this example differs.

Comment: Oh, I see... I thought the html/php code you show of `div#height_weight_table` was the content of the `corp_health.php` file. Tomorrow morning I'll check modified post to see if I can't give you a hand.